# How to structure my code to prevent whitespaces between answers in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a javascript that calculates all the possible options based on inputs and I currently have the code structured as shown below so that all the possible options are displayed on new lines. If option 1 is not possible based on inputs, I have the javascript display the value of option 1 as "" or blank.

When HTML displays the answers, there is an additional whitespace below the Answer: line as option1 is blank and there is a break.

Is there a method where I can display the possible options on separate lines, but if option1 is "" or blank there is not an additional whitespace below the Answer: line?

I would like it to display it like:

Answer:

Option2

Option3

Instead of displaying it like below:

Answer:

(This part would be blank as option1="")

Option2

Option3

```
Answer:
<p></p>
<span id="option1"></span>
<br>
<span id="option2"></span>
<br>
<span id="option3"></span>
<br>
```

```
JAVASCRIPT
<script>
option1="";
option2="";
option3="";

if (input > 0) {
option2="Option 2";
option3="Option 3";
}

if (input <= 0) {
option1="Option 1";
}

document.getElementById("option1").innerHTML = option1;
document.getElementById("option2").innerHTML = option2;
document.getElementById("option3").innerHTML = option3;
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo element in CSS

*Note: I have removed your `<br>` and used CSS to manage the space between the spans*

```css
span {
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

span:empty {
  display: none
}
```

```html
Answer:
<p></p>
<span id="option1"></span>
<!-- Has no content -->
<span id="option2">Has content</span>
<span id="option3">Also has content</span>
```

With content it would look like this (without changing the CSS)

```css
span {
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

span:empty {
  display: none
}
```

```html
Answer:
<p></p>
<span id="option1">Now also has content</span>
<span id="option2">Has content</span>
<span id="option3">Also has content</span>
```

Comment: this is so much better and simple than jquery .(hide) fonction

Answer (score 1):

```
<p></p>
<div id="option1">Option 1</div>
<br>
<div id="option2">Option 2</div>
<br>
<div id="option3">Option 3</div>
<br> 


<script>

if (input > 0) {
document.getElementById("option1").display="none";
}

if (input <= 0) {
document.getElementById("option2").display="none";
document.getElementById("option3").display="none";
}
```

Using div instead of span will fix your issue. Span is an inline element whereas div is a block element. Inline and block elements behave differently.